# Why do erroneous require calls not throw an error when running npm build?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new in nodeJS, I added a js file in my project that includes this:

```
// Instantiate Couchbase and Ottoman
var couchbase=require('couchbase');
var ottoman=require('ottoman');

// Build my cluster object and open a new cluster
var myCluster = new couchbase.Cluster('localhost:8091');
var myBucket = myCluster.openBucket('bikeShop');
ottoman.store = new ottoman.CbStoreAdapter(myBucket, couchbase);
//ottoman.bucket=myBucket;

// Build my "schema" from my model files
require('./model/employee');
require('./model/customer');
require('./model/bike');

// Build the necessary indexes to function
ottoman.ensureIndices(function(){});
```

I don't have employee, customer or bike in the project, but nevertheless

```
npm run compile
```

works fine and also

```
npm build
```

I also copied the content in the file

```
main.ts
```

with the same result

Comment: @Olli it does throw an error.

Comment: @SandroRey are you sure that this file is imported anywhere? If it isn't imported and isn't the main entry file neither then Node doesn't even see it, so no errors are thrown. Try doing something like this `node your-file-from-question.js`

Comment: Also, you may not have `./model/employee.js` file but you may have for example `./model/employee/index.js` and it will work fine